# How to pass values to a function that expects a Class

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have a method for creating a user on my firebase db, It expects a instance of a specific model.

But I have no idea how I take the values combine them and then pass then to the function as that type.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Entry } from '../entry.model';
import { MemberService } from 'src/app/member.service';
import { Member } from 'src/app/member.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  entry: Entry;
  member: Member;
  constructor(private memberservice: MemberService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
//function being called from front end button with input fields that pass values
  create(surName: string, pass: string, color: string){
     //Should call createMember();
     //Id,Priority gets set here not by the user
  }
```

The Service function:

```
  createMember(member: Member){
    return this.firestore.collection('members').add(member);
  }
```

The Model

```
export class Member {
    id: string;
    surname: string;
    color: string;
    password: string;
    priority: number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance where TS [Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) would be a better fit instead of a class. Interface supports type-checking without the unnecessary "bloat" of class.

Try the following

Model

```js
export interface Member {
  id: string;
  surname: string;
  color: string;
  password: string;
  priority: number;
}
```

You could then create an object of type `Member`.

```js
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  // Function being called from front end button with input fields that pass values
  create(surName: string, pass: string, color: string) {
     const member = {
       id: <set id>,
       surname: surName,
       color: color,
       password: pass,
       priority: <set priority>       
     } as Member;

     this.memberservice.createMember(member)
       .then((res) => console.log('Set member with ID:', id)
       .catch((error) => console.log('Error setting member:', id);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, Interesting Im so use to interfaces in c# I kind of forget they work a bit different here. 
Thank you for the nice example